# Anycubic resin printer not printing beyond the first layer

Tags: resin

I recently acquired a Anycubic Photon Zero and I'm having trouble printing anything that's not pre-loaded from that company.

I create my own models in Blender, put them through the Photon Workshop slicer software as well as download other models from the web for personal use and only the bottom or 1st layer will print! But anything that came pre-loaded as a demo from Anycubic prints fine.

Is there something I'm missing? What should I be checking for in the slicer software? Clearly the model is ready as you can see it all in light-blue on the printer/thumb drive, and as I said, it prints the first layer correctly.

I have calibrated the printer previously.

It's level, I even have a new resin resevoir with a clean film on the bottom.

What I noticed when I try to print vs what any cubic provides is, you know how the print head or plate moves up and down consistently. It almost seems any of these problem models, the printing plate stays in a static position for quite a while before it moves onto the next.

The screen shows what appears to be the correct layer being printed but I noticed even the plate doesn't move down back into the resin as it should.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Ps - I'm using I believe their brand resin, the plant-based one.

Answer (score 2):

Although you've noted that you have run the model through the slicer, what's missing is if the preview shows you more than one layer. Near the bottom of your post, I think you're indicating that more than one layer is being displayed. In the preview, you should see images indicating that the layers are changing as the slider/progress bar is moved.

The first layers of a resin print are often tens of seconds long, to establish a more cured bond with the build plate. Depending on your settings this can be four to six layers running many seconds, but once "cleared" of the foundation, the duration should be shorter.

Consider to use a different slicer as a means of comparison. Also, consider to download an STL of any form from a different resource, something you have not created. Blender is known for creating unprintable models.

Additionally, you can save resin by not pouring any in the vat during these tests. If the characteristics are as you describe, you can examine the movement and the layer displays as the print job progresses, while not wasting product.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Correct, in the slicer software it is showing the progress if I move the bar. I think that part is correct.

I'll try to create a file based off an STL not in Blender, or just get an STL from the web and give it a go. Yeah sometimes I try not pouring in as much resin - makes cleanup a bit quicker.